# Remove redundancy from similar methods

Tags: java, coding-style

I have typical 'clean code' nature problem. I have two methods. They are similar

```
public void setValue(String arg1, String arg2){
    Fragment frag1 = foundElem(arg1);
    // ... do something with frag1, do something else

    doSomething(arg2);
}

public void setValue(String arg1){
    Fragment frag1 = foundElem(arg1);
    // ... do something with frag1, do something else

    doSomething();
}
```

I am trying to find the solution how to remove redundancy and transform two similiar methods into something less repetitive.

I thought about removing second method and checking if arg2 is null or not, but I try not to use null as a solution for my problems especially i don't think that calling method setValue("FirstArgument" , "") is good habit.

```
public void setValue(String arg1, String arg2){
    Fragment frag1 = foundElem(arg1);
    // ... do something with frag1, do something else

    if(arg2 != null)
        doSomething(arg2);
    else
        doSomething();
}
```

I also thought about 'Optional' argument. What do you think about this? I try to make my code as clean as possible so refactoring is typical task at the end of my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways in which this can be solved. The checking for `null` way as you mentioned, but here are some other ways.

Call the method with lesser arguments from the other (alt 1):

```
public void setValue(String arg1) {
    Fragment frag1 = foundElem(arg1);
    // ... do something with frag1, do something else

    doSomething();
}

public void setValue(String arg1, String arg2) {
    setValue(arg1);
    doSomething(arg2);
}
```

(Note that this will call `doSomething` twice. That may not work for you.)

Call the method with lesser arguments from the other (alt 2):

```
public void setValue(String arg1) {
    Fragment frag1 = foundElem(arg1);
    // ... do something with frag1, do something else
}

public void setValue(String arg1, String arg2) {
    setValue(arg1);
    doSomething(arg2);
}
```

(If `doSomething()` (without arguments) actually doesn't do much.)

Create a third `private` method that is called from both `public` methods. This method will contain code common to both `public` methods:

(The method can't be called `setValue(String)`, that would clash with the public method. Make up a good name that describes what it does.)

```
private void setValuePrivate(String arg1) {
    Fragment frag1 = foundElem(arg1);
    // ... do something with frag1, do something else
}

public void setValue(String arg1) {
    setValuePrivate(arg1);
    doSomething();
}

public void setValue(String arg1, String arg2) {
    setValuePrivate(arg1);
    doSomething(arg2);
}
```

There are probably other ways to do this that I have not mentioned.